# How to disable TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (or, how to set TLSv1.3 ciphers) in postfix

Tags: ssl, postfix, cipher

I have the following in my TLS configuration, but the only problem I have is that `TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` is a 128 bit cipher, and I would like to remove it:

```
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = ultra
smtp_tls_eecdh_grade = ultra
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL, ARIA, RSA, AES128
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL, ARIA, RSA, AES128
smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL, ARIA, RSA, AES128
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL, ARIA, RSA, AES128
tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
```

And if I try to change `tls_high_cipherlist` to somehow disable the TLSv1.3 cipher, I cannot:

```
tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:!TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Adding `!TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` at the end doesn't work. How can I achieve this? Even if I add the required ciphers at the end, it won't work that way either.

I am able to do this on Apache by doing:

```
SSLCipherSuite TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

But, I couldn't find anything related to TLSv1.3 in postfix.

The TLSv1.2 Cipher suites that my server supports:

```
 xc030   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384       ECDH 384   AESGCM      256      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384              
 xcca8   ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305       ECDH 384   ChaCha20    256      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256        
 x9f     DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384         DH 4096    AESGCM      256      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Comment: You can't disable TLS 1.3 cipher suites, and shouldn't be trying anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why though?? Is it bad? I am able to disable it on apache.. what about postfix?

Comment: @EsaJokinen So, should I also enable it in my apache installation right?

Comment: @EsaJokinen Maybe someone should inform SSLLabs about this??? Because they interpret it as weak. They do not seem to be following RFC standards in this case, hence misguiding people who follow it.

Comment: @EsaJokinen, what about TLSv1.2? My server only supports some: `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`, `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` and `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 `.

Comment: I just compiled my comments into a complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLS 1.3 has mandatory-to-implement cipher suites ([RFC 8446, 9.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-9.1)) you should  not try and remove:

> A TLS-compliant application MUST implement the
> `TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` [[GCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#ref-GCM)] cipher suite and SHOULD implement the
> `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` [[GCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#ref-GCM)] and `TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256`
> [[RFC8439](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8439)] cipher suites (see [Appendix B.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#appendix-B.4)).
>
> A TLS-compliant application MUST support digital signatures with
> `rsa_pkcs1_sha256` (for certificates), `rsa_pss_rsae_sha256` (for
> CertificateVerify and certificates), and `ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256`.  A
> TLS-compliant application MUST support key exchange with `secp256r1`
> (NIST P-256) and SHOULD support key exchange with `X25519` [[RFC7748](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748)].

TLS 1.3 has already removed all weak cipher suites by design ([RFC 8446, 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-1.2)), so this is not something you should be worrying about.

Getting 100% from Qualys SSL Labs [Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) should not be your major goal. They have their own [Rating Guide](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide) that specifies their scoring e.g. for [Cipher Strength](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide#cipher-strength). They have decided that 128 bit ciphers are not worth 100%, and they do not make exceptions based on standards. However, it still gives an A+ grading.

> | Cipher strength | Score |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0 bits (no encryption) | 0% |
> | < 128 bits (e.g., 40, 56) | 20% |
> | < 256 bits (e.g., 128, 168) | 80% |
> | = 256 bits (e.g., 256) | 100% |

Instead, you should be focusing on a [suitable tradeoff between security and compatibility](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/210165/how-do-i-know-which-cipher-suites-can-be-disabled/210167#210167).

Comment: Anything I am doing wrong with TLSv1.2 btw?? Just give some comments on it, i will proceed :)

Comment: I've linked my answers on the subject already twice and currently don't have much to add to it. :)

Comment: And, I use `secp384r1`, but the quote you have included, states `secp256r1`, is it mandatory to use `secp256r1` if I have `secp384r1`? Btw, my RSA key size is 4096 bit, and it is from LetsEncrypt.

Comment: Well, I have similar setup using `secp384r1` and a 4096 bit RSA from Let's Encrypt. However, you should notice that the 4096 RSA doesn't truly add security, as long as it's signed with 2048 bit CA certificates. And that's not going to change fast.

Comment: I just realised secp256r1 doesn't work, I think because I have a 4096 bit cert

Comment: ***A TLS-compliant application MUST support key exchange with secp256r1 (NIST P-256) and SHOULD support key exchange with X25519***, I have a 4096 bit cert, duh

Comment: I have edited my question with more info

Comment: That's not a good idea. I'd revert the edit and ask another question. It's impossible to keep on track and modify existing answers to meet the new criteria in a modified question. This is not a discussion forum but a Q/A site.